# Free torsion part of centralizer of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, torsion-groups

Suppose $G$ is a cyclic group $C_{5} <S_{5}$. Does anybody know what the torsion-free part of the centralizer of this group is?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Torsion free implies infinite, right?

Comment: Is the group an arbitrary cyclic group, or specifically $C_5$? It’s not clear to me what’s being asked, to be honest.

Comment: why do u think you answered my question? you didn't don't beg for vote

Answer (score 2):

Each nontrivial torsion-free group is infinite; contrapositively, each finite group has torsion. Thus there is no torsion-free part as $\lvert S_5\rvert<\infty$.

Comment: how about if I change $S_{5}$ with GL(5,Z)?

Comment: Your question has been anwered. If you have a followup question, you should ask it in a new post, not in a comment to an answer to this question.

Comment: Agreed with the above. This answer seems like it should be accepted.